# Given a dataset and multiple models which could have produced it, how can i calculate the propability with which, each model could have produced it?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Lets suppose we have a dataset: (yi/xi) i=1,2,...n
And a few possible models which could explain the data. For example:
y(x) = 7x + 13 or y(x) = 25x^3 - 5x or y(x) = e^sin(x)+23^x or something like that, you get the idea.
Does there exist some kind of formula, which i can apply and it gives me some kind of propability, that the dataset is produced by one of the models?

I was thinking about bayes theorem but i dont really know how to apply it to datasets and functions. From my limited understanding of it it should be really good to predict more accurately if i measure one more data: (yn+1/xn+1)
My other idea was using the coefficient determination which is given with: [Sum from i=1 to n (yi-ymodel)^2] over [Sum from i=1 to n (yi-yaverage)^2]

Comment: To compute a probability, something has to be random. What is in your case?

Comment: You are right. The Data doesnt fit the models perfectly. There are some uncertainties hidden there. Uncertainty in y and x.